# background image zoomin Effect.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my code

## html

```
<h1 class="logo-title"><span>DAVE</span></h1>
```

## css

```
h1.logo-title {background: url(bg.jpg) no-repeat;background-position: 50% 100%;-webkit-background-clip: text;}
```

I am trying to use my background image zoomin and zoomout animation effect like those websites. here is demo.
http://wowslider.com/jquery-slider-bar-kenburns-demo.html
http://owwwlab.com/toranj/index-2.html

please give me any sollution for my background image. Anybody help me out in this situation. ??

Comment: Check out this reference link..a complete tutorial..http://www.uiupdates.com/create-zoom-or-scaling-effect-on-image-using-css3-animation-and-transition/

Comment: i just fixed with this way... but the problem is ... background image is shaking .. i am looking for smooth animation. . do you give me any solution .... here is my last update jsfiddle.net/sgy3dakt/9.. i am just looking like this uiupdates.com/responsive/Demo1/zoom.html –

Answer (score 0):

You may get the idea here:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="zoom-in strawberry">
</div>
<button onclick="zoomin(100, 2, 500)">Zoom In</button>
```

**CSS:**

```
.strawberry{
    background-image: url('http://dreamatico.com/data_images/strawberry/strawberry-6.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.zoom-in{
    display: block;
    width: 400px;
    height:350px;
    background-size: 400px;
}
```

**Script:**

```
function zoomin(interval, sizeChangeEveryInterval, stopResizeWhenSizeReached){
    var timeout = setInterval(function(){
        var target = $(".zoom-in")
        var bgposx = target.css('background-position-x') ? parseInt(target.css('background-position-x')) : 0;
        target.css('background-position-x',(bgposx - sizeChangeEveryInterval) + "px");
        var bgposy = target.css('background-position-y') ? parseInt(target.css('background-position-y')) : 0;
        target.css('background-position-y',(bgposy - sizeChangeEveryInterval) + "px");
        var bgsize = !isNaN(parseInt(target.css('background-size'))) ? parseInt(target.css('background-size')) : 100;
        target.css('background-size',(bgsize + sizeChangeEveryInterval) + "px");
        if(stopResizeWhenSizeReached < bgsize) clearInterval(timeout)
    }, interval)
}
```

Here's my Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ThisIsMarkSantiago/xm1zp09g/

Comment: i just fixed with this way... but the problem is ... background image is shaking .. i am looking for smooth animation. . do you give me any solution .... here is my last update jsfiddle.net/sgy3dakt/9.. i am just looking like this uiupdates.com/responsive/Demo1/zoom.html –

Answer (score 0):

easiest way to do it is by just putting an img tag behind your content and then `transform: scale(110%,110%);`. Animate it using css:

```
div.container
{
    position: relative;
}
img.background
{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    left: 0px;
    // .. etc etc
    transform: scale(100%, 100%);
    transform-origin: 50% 50%; // wherever you want the 'midpoint' to be at.
    transition: transform 5s linear;
}
img.background.active
{
    transform: scale(110%, 110%);
}
```

easy does it.

you could of course do this with just `background-image` but then you will have a tougher time switching from image to image.

Comment: i just fixed with this way... but the problem is ... background image is shaking .. i am looking for smooth animation. . do you give me any solution .... here is my last update jsfiddle.net/sgy3dakt/9.. i am just looking like this uiupdates.com/responsive/Demo1/zoom.html –

Comment: the shaking is probably caused by performance issues on your machine. Here it works fine :-) Cool effect, never thought about doing that!

Comment: If by shaking you mean 'it accelerates, stops, accelerates, stop', that is because of the timing-function being 'ease-in' and not 'linear'.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this issue also using pure CSS3 animations.  Though it [might not be supported on every platform](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation)

Here is a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/albertmatyi/sgy3dakt/) (quickly hacked together & tested in chrome):

```css
html, body {
    min-width: 400px;
    min-height: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.container {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: #efefef;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.image {
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
    animation-name: zoom;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 10s;
    animation-duration: 10s;
    -webkit-animation-direction: normal;
    animation-direction: normal;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.image-1{
    background-image: url(http://www.chip.de/ii/917741674_393fa282fa.jpeg);
}
.image-2{
    -webkit-animation-delay: 5s;
    animation-delay: 5s;
    background-image: url(http://www.chip.de/ii/917741714_fe3259c85e.jpeg);
}

@keyframes zoom {
   0% {transform: scale(1,1); z-index: 2;}
   49% {transform: scale(2,2);}
    50% {opacity: 0}
}


@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
   0% {-webkit-transform: scale(1,1); z-index: 2;}
    49% {-webkit-transform: scale(2,2);}
    50% {opacity: 0}
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="image image-1" style=""></div>
    <div class="image image-2" style=""></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please look at this. http://jsfiddle.net/sgy3dakt/7/ But i want the text be fixed, only background of the text will zoom in/ out. text will not zoom in/out.

Comment: There: http://jsfiddle.net/albertmatyi/sgy3dakt/8/ . This time we animate the background image, but you have to take manual care of the sizing and positioning. Hope it helped

Comment: Still there is a problem.... image are going left to right or right to left with zoom effect but i want image will fixed in a position and create just zoom in and zoom out effect. please help :) just like your previous example http://jsfiddle.net/albertmatyi/sgy3dakt/

Comment: As I've mentioned it in my previous comment, if you apply the effect on the background image via `background-position` / `background-size` then you have to take care of the pixel values manually, meaning you have to calculate them properly in order to get the right effect. So it is not that easy anymore as with the `scale` `transform`. So basically right now you have to take every image separately and specify the pixel precies transformations yourself.

Comment: i fixed the position and size... but the problem is ... background image is shaking .. i am looking for smooth animation. . do you give me any solution .... here is my last update http://jsfiddle.net/sgy3dakt/9/.. i am just looking for like this http://www.uiupdates.com/responsive/Demo1/zoom.html

Comment: I don't believe I can help you. The main problem is that for performance you should use the gpu accelerated `transforms` but that does not work with your `background-clip: text` property. As you can see **[here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/text-backgrounds-and-gradients-with-background-clip)** others use the same approach as I outlined it. I don't believe there is an easy css only workaround this problem. Maybe try solving with svgs (just an idea to test).